# Update multiple running totals when past items change

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, cumulative-sum

I have a table (in SQL Server 2014) including multiple running totals (by different dates) - not an ideal design but imagine a very large number of rows and users able to pick a specified time period - we don't want to calculate SUMs from the start of time to get the running total to that period every time.
I am looking for an elegant way to update those running totals when multiple rows are updated.

The actual scenario is an account reconciliation - the table stores money transactions for which we have the event date (e.g. when a thing was sold), the transaction date (e.g. the invoice date) and the payment date (when the invoice was paid). For each of these there is a running total, e.g. (much simplified)

```
CREATE TABLE MyTransaction (
  Id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
  EventDate DATETIME NOT NULL,
  TransactionDate DATETIME,
  PaymentDate DATETIME,
  Amount INT, -- assume whole numbers for sake of it
  RunningTotalByEventDate INT,
  RunningTotalByTransactionDate INT,
  RunningTotalByPaymentDate INT,
  IsCancelled BIT DEFAULT (0)
)
```

... with indexes on dates as needed, etc. and assume for sake of example that the date/times are unique (in practice there are uniqueifiers and other stuff).

Inserting a transaction is fine(ish) - best I have come up with is three separate queries, each updating the running total by the relevant date... or one query with logic... so after inserting a new row (with obviously-named variables passed inot a stored proc)...

```
UPDATE MyTransaction SET RunningTotalByEventDate += @Amount
 WHERE EventDate > @EventDate
```

and so on for the other two running totals, or a single query like...

```
UPDATE MyTransaction 
   SET RunningTotalByEventDate += CASE WHEN EventDate > @EventDate THEN @Amount ELSE 0 END,
       RunningTotalByTransactionDate += CASE WHEN TransactionDate > @TransactionDate THEN @Amount ELSE 0 END,
       RunningTotalByPaymentDate += CASE WHEN PaymentDate > @PaymentDate THEN @Amount ELSE 0 END
 WHERE EventDate > @EventDate
    OR TransactionDate > @TransactionDate
    OR PaymentDate > @PaymentDate
```

Now I need to cancel transactions, e.g. an invoice is written off - the requirement is to leave the row in, but remove the effect - so the row stays with its Amount, but the cancelled flag is set and the row has no effect on the running totals. Unfortunately an invoice may have multiple transactions (e.g. several part payments), so there could be several transaction rows to update.

My best option so far for updating the multiple running totals is to loop/cursor around the (expected to be few) updated rows and reduce the subsequent running totals much as we increased them when adding a row - so for each time around the loop we have the three update queries (or one with logic) to update the three running totals.

A single UPDATE won't work, since it will only update a target row once (and if two part payments are being cancelled, we need to update it twice to take off each amount). I've played variously with windowed functions but cannot see a way to do this neatly with a single query set-wise.

So given a list of `MyTransaction.Id` values to cancel (e.g. in a table, table variable or CSV string list), what's the best way to update the various running totals?

Any ideas (and apologies for the rambling question) are very welcome.

Comment: Could you please provide some sample data? Eases up the process of developing a suggestion e.g. in SQLFiddle... anyways: did you consider using a view for the calculation od the running totals?